# What the answer of preposition in this sentence

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> The investigator asked the witness where he was __ the night of the murder

Is the answer

1. at
2. of

Comment: In this particular case, you also have the option of leaving out the preposition entirely (though it would be *implied* as "on").

Answer (score 0):

I would put 'on' there instead of 'at' or 'of'. 'On' is usually used to refer to dates, e.g. 'I did this *on* Tuesday', 'Christmas falls *on* the 25th of December', etc.